# HTML - Page is opening at random scroll point

Tags: html, css

I've created a webpage and found weird problem.
When I try to get to subpage from homepage, subpage appears, but **scrolled down.** It could appear at top, and it **does** on computer - but **not** on a phone. 
There is a code:

**HTML (from body section):**

```
<div id="top"><a href="some_link">Go to main</a></div>
<div id="title" class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="space">
      <span class="centerer"></span>
      <span class="centered"><h1>Some centered stuff there</h1></span>
    </div>
    <div id="changelog_btn">
      <a href="#changelog">
        <span class="centerer"></span>
        <span class="centered">Changelog</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="dl_btn">
      <a href="#download">
        <span class="centerer"></span>
        <span class="centered">Download</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="changelog" class="slide">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="space">
      <span class="centerer"></span>
      <span class="centered"><h1>Changelog</h1><div class="up_btn"><a href="#top">(Top)</a></div></span>
    </div>
    <textarea readonly autofocus>
Some changelog stuff
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
<div id="download">
  <div id="content" class="slide">
    <div class="space">
      <span class="centerer"></span>
      <span class="centered"><h1>Download</h1><div class="up_btn"><a href="#top">(Top)</a></div></span>
    </div>
    Header<br>
    <div id="dl_btn">
      <a href="file.link" download>
      <span class="centerer"></span>
      <span class="centered">Download file</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 240px) {
html {
  font-family: 'AtomicAge';
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
h1 {
  margin: auto;
}
.space {
  height: 25%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

#changelog_btn a, #dl_btn a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20%;
  height: 5%;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

#changelog_btn a, #dl_btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#changelog_btn a:hover, #dl_btn a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}
.centered, .centerer {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.centerer {
  height: 100%;
}
.up_btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.up_btn a:hover {
  color: white;
}
#title {
  background-image: url("_images/bg1.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#changelog:before, #changelog {
  background-image: url("_images/bg2.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#download {
  background-image: url("_images/bg3.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#top a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#top a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
}
@media only screen
and (max-width: 1080px) {
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can correct?

Comment: Are you sure you're not linking to an anchor point in your URL when viewed on the computer?

Comment: Do try out on different browers as different browsers support different level html, css, js. You will find the main cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the autofocus attribute applied to the text area :)

Comment: Oh **god**, it was... uh, I can't even describe ease of solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be slightly scrolled down on the computer as well (at least somewhat on my screen).  I would agree that this issue is very odd.  I would recommend inserting the following JavaScript at the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {window.scrollTo(0,0)};
</script>
```

Comment: Thats a hack to get over with it! Not a actual solution to it.

Comment: When you get a better solution, use that.

Comment: William Robinson (comment below) found the answer, but still, this is good too and I'll use it - just in other way. Thanks! :)